# How can I define type within a NSArray

Tags: swift, syntactic-sugar

Given 'results' in an NSArray of NSDictionary objects

how can I **remove** the need of the temporary constant **r**:

```
for result in results {
    let r :NSDictionary = result as NSDictionary
    println(r.valueForKey("heading"))
}
```

Comment: I don't know, does `for result: NSDictionary in results` work?

Comment: @GradyPlayer Type annotation does not match contextual type 'AnyObject'

Comment: worth a try, I guess.

Comment: What exactly is the type of the results array? Is it `[NSDictionary]`? Can you show its declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference to the rescue.  Explicitly typing result 'as NSDictionary' should work but type inference already knows that the loop iterator is an NSDictionary. The following code will correctly output 'value1' and 'value2'.

```
var results = [NSDictionary]()
results.append(["heading": "value1", "anotherKey": "anotherValue1"])
results.append(["heading": "value2", "anotherKey": "anotherValue1"])

for result in results {
    println(result.valueForKey("heading"))
}
```

Comment: of course my memory claims to have tried this first... but yep, it works! thanks. I did try "as NSDictionary" but the compiler wasn't happy with it added after "for result " and before "in results {"

Comment: The syntax for casting in a for loop is `for element in collection as CollectionType` or `for element:ElementType in collection`, not `for element as ElementType in collection`.